# Random sample table with Hive, but including matching rows

Tags: hive, hiveql, random

I have a large table containing a `userID` column and other user variable columns, and I would like to use Hive to extract a random sample of users based on their `userID`. Furthermore, sometimes these users will be on multiple rows and if a randomly selected `userID` is contained in other parts of the table I would like to extract those rows too.

I had a look at [the Hive sampling documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Sampling) and I see that something like this can be done to extract a 1% sample:

```
SELECT * FROM source 
TABLESAMPLE (1 PERCENT) s;
```

but I am not sure how to add the constraint where I would like all other instances of those 1% `userID`s selected too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use rand() to split the data randomly and with the proper percent of userid in your category.  I recommend rand() because setting the seed to something make the results repeatable.

```
select c.*
from 
(select userID
, if(rand(5555)<0.1, 'test','train') end as type
    from
    (select userID 
    from mytable 
    group by userID
    ) a
) b
right outer join
(select *
from userID
) c
on a.userid=c.userid
where type='test'
;
```

This is set up for entity level modeling purposes, which is why I have test and train as types.

Comment: what is `test` and `train` in the query?

Comment: The code splits the data by that field.  I would use Train portion of data to build a model then use Test portion to evaluate the model performance.  This is a standard thing to do when building predictive models.